# No module named 'beautifulsoup4' even if the module is downloaded in the anaconda

Tags: jupyter-notebook

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-f33cf0cb8fd3> in <module>
----> 1 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4
```

beautifulsoup4 is downloaded in my Anaconda Navigator but it shoes that no module is found.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
!conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix} beautifulsoup4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```